# How to add geolocation attributes to an LDAP account

Tags: geolocation, ldap, openldap

I have an LDAP users database mapped as objects of class posixAccount, inetOrgPerson and top.

I need to add latitude and longitude attributes to the users. However, theses attributes do not seem to be present on these classes (and also not in others). inetOrgPerson presents only references such as postalAddress, street, etc.

Is it possible to add a new class or a new attribute to an existing LDAP class? Or is there any other solution path I'm missing?

I'm using openldap server with phpldapadmin (although these are not hard constraints).

Thanks a lot,
alan

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible to add attribute types to a standard (RFC) object class, you shouldn't do that.  The vCard-4.0 draft conveniently defines an attribute latLong ([section 3.14](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gryphon-ldap-schema-vcard4-00#page-9)).  You create an auxiliary objectClass with that attribute type that you later can use to add GPS coordinates to your entries.

Create a file "geolocation.schema" like:

```
# latLong
# Represents a geographical location using the WGS84 data coordinates
# as used by GPS, like: -33.92;151.28
 attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.33592.1.3.14 NAME 'latLong'
   EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
   SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
   SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 
 )

# geoLocation
# The geoLocation auxiliary class allows GPS coordinates to be added
# to an object
 objectclass ( your-company-oid-prefix-as-provided-by-IANA.your-oc-convention 
   NAME 'geoLocation'
   DESC ''
   AUXILIARY
   MAY ( latLong )
 )
```

In your `slapd.conf` file add an `include` statement for your schema file. The new object class is available after you restart the LDAP server.

If your organization doesn't already have an OID prefix, [get one](http://www.oid-info.com/faq.htm#10). For tests you can fake one.

Typed and not tested...

Comment: marabu, thanks a lot for your answer! It didn't work as is, but I'll analyse it further and post what went wrong. It looks like a geolocation.diff file is missing.

Comment: How can I generate the geolocation.ldif file?

Comment: As an OpenLDAP administrator, locate the folder with your schema extensions, copy & paste the schema entries from above into your preferred text editor, and save as geolocation.schema.  Don't forget to adjust the geoLocation OID.